# TypeScript definition files

Tags: typescript, definitions

I'm playing with TypesScript, but the compiler complains when I use browser types such as HTMLCanvasElement. I guess I need definition files for these types.
I bet there is a repository of definition files for the DOM and for most popular frameworks, but Google has not been able to help me find it.

Do you guys know of such a repository?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `lib.d.ts` that is included in the source ([http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#bin%2flib.d.ts](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#bin/lib.d.ts)) contains definitions for most of the DOM related stuff. If you are using Visual Studio, you should consider downloading the tools which includes a template where `lib.d.ts` is bundled.

If anything is missing, I think you can use the `declare` syntax.

Comment: This looks like what I were looking for. Thanks.

Comment: you can look at http://www.tsdpm.com/ and https://github.com/Diullei/tsd#readme too.

Answer (score 27):

In addition to what @Christoffer has said for the DOM, @Boris Yankov has a really useful repository here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped with definition files for <strike>more than thirty, one hundred and thirty</strike> close to **two hundred** libraries(and counting!).

<strike>There's even a manager for the type definition files now: http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/</strike> (**Do not follow: link is now NSFW spam**)

**AND**: Quite a lot of definition files are now on nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=TypeScript

Comment: That looks very useful indeed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JcFx Do you know of any plugin or Grunt task that can create definitions for newly created, local typescript files? E.g. I have a *_definitions.ts* file that contains all my definitions (local and plugins e.g. AngularJS). This file then gets referenced from every other .ts file. It would be great if something could update *_definitions.ts* with every new typescript file I create, automatically.

Comment: TSD has been deprecated in favor of Typings now: https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/tsd.md

Comment: We may need to update the link for type definition file manager. It redirects to something completely different now.